# ¿Cómo se hace para que mi script en bash sea case-insensitive?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

¿Cómo se hace para que mi script en bash se case insensitive?
¿y por que no funcionan las cosas que estoy intentando?
por un lado shopt me da el error `arranca.sh: 39: shopt: not found`
Por otro `{$ur,,}"` y "{$3^^}" simplemente no tienen ningun efecto.

```
#!/bin/bash
pregVariasOpt() {    
    
        repetir="si"    
        while [ $repetir = "si" ]    
        do    
                echo "$1"    
                read ur    
                repetir="no"    
                if [ "{$2,,}" != "{$ur,,}" ] && [ "{$3^^}" != "{$ur^^}" ]    
                then    
                        echo "fallaste!!! ¿Quieres volver a intentarlo?"    
                        read again_user    
                        if [ "s" = "$again_user" ]    
                        then    
                                repetir="si"    
                        fi    
                fi    
        done    
        echo "$2"    
        echo "$3"    
       shopt -u nocasematch    
}    
pregVariasOpt "2" "Dos" "dOS"
```

la version de bash es:
GNU bash, versión 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: sep! pero gracias por verlo!

Comment: `shopt -p` responde algo? Con qué comando ejecutas el script?

Comment: para ejecutar el script uso:
$ sh ~./arranca.sh
y
~$ shopt -p | grep case
devuelve: 
shopt -u nocaseglob
shopt -u nocasematch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he averiguado por qué no funciona lo que no funciona, pero:

```
 18 pregVariasOpt() {
 19 #o      shopt -s nocasematch
 21 sol1=$(echo $2 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
 22 sol2=$(echo $3 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
 23 enun=$(echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
 24         repetir="si"
 25         while [ $repetir = "si" ]
 26         do
 27                 echo "$1"
 28                 read ur
 29                 userr=$(echo $ur | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
 30                 repetir="no"
 31                 if [ "$sol1" != "$userr" ] && [ "$sol2" != "$userr" ]
 32                 then
 34                         echo "fallaste!!! ¿Quieres volver a intentarlo?"
 35                         read again_user
 36                         if [ "s" = "$again_user" ]
 37                         then
 38                                 repetir="si"
 39                         fi
 40                 fi
 41         done
 42         echo "$2"
 43         echo "$3"
 44 #       shopt -u nocasematch
 45 }
```